# How do i set text input as int in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i am trying to set the kivy textinput as an int to use it as a variable, which will be used to send a certain amount of messages.

This is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class layy(App):

    def build(self):

        b = Button(text='Start Spam')
        b.bind(on_press=self.bott())

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        sublay1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        sublay2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        sublay3 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        layout.add_widget(sublay1)
        sublay1.add_widget(a)

        layout.add_widget(sublay2)
        sublay2.add_widget(c)
        sublay2.add_widget(d)

        layout.add_widget(sublay3)
        sublay3.add_widget(b)

        return layout

    def bott(self):
        global a
        a = TextInput(hint_text='insert text to spam')
        global c
        c = TextInput(hint_text=' insert time till beginning',
                      input_filter='int')
        global d
        d = TextInput(hint_text='insert amount', input_filter='int')

        value3 = a
        global ti
        ti = value3.text

        ii = int(c)
        tt = int(d)

        base = 0
        time.sleep(tt)
        while base < ii:
            pyautogui.typewrite(ti)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            base = base + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    layy().run()
```

This is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/fares/PycharmProjects/droidspm/main.py", line 67, in <module>
     layy().run()
   File "/home/fares/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/home/fares/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "/home/fares/PycharmProjects/droidspm/main.py", line 14, in build
     b.bind(on_press = self.bott())
   File "/home/fares/PycharmProjects/droidspm/main.py", line 52, in bott
     ii= int(c)
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TextInput'
```

Are there any tips? I tried converting c and d to strings first but i got this error instead:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput object at 0x7f16597e7900>'
```

I cant seem to resolve the error, and i cant find anything online on how to. sorry if this is simple, i'm new to python.

Comment: integer = int(string) will convert any string to an integer if it can be one (if it is a number)

Comment: so it cant be done? is there another way to achieve what i need then?

Comment: Out of context - rather than using ```global```, use *instance attribute* instead. As simple as ```self.a = 1```. Plus, I see tons of violation of python coding guideline which your IDE Pycharm provides.

Comment: it can be done, I think I just showed you how to do it. If I wasn't clear, to do this, you need to cast the string (a variable) to an int. You can say variable = int(variable)

Comment: the problem is that textinputs in kivy are not strings. i tried converting the textinput to a string and the string to an int but  i got an error

Answer (score 0):

On these specific lines:

```
ii = int(c)
tt = int(d)
```

You already got text using `text` property here, but why not for above?

```
ti = value3.text
```

*value3(= a)*, *b* and *c* is all `TextInput` instances, it's just like  you've been expecting to get integer by doing `int(dict)`.

---

Plus, UI programing is usually made up with callbacks, writing sequential code with widgets just don't makes any sense. I'm not sure if your code worked as you've intended or not, but function `bott` won't wait until you actually type in something and keep on.

Here's simple demonstration of how kivy program would look like instead.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class InputField(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(multiline=False, input_filter = "int", **kwargs)
        self.bind(on_text_validate=self.on_enter)

    def on_enter(self, value):
        output = int(value.text)

        print(f"{output} - type: {type(output)}")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout_main = BoxLayout()
        layout_main.add_widget(InputField())
        return layout_main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

for respective input of *(123, 1230908)*:

```
123 - type: <class 'int'>
1230938 - type: <class 'int'>
```

Just using class `InputField` where you used `TextInput` would be enough - though use of `global` is hardly recommended, it will work.